# Testing simple FizzBuzz function inJS

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

I have a simple FizzBuzz function, and have to implement test for it, spent whole day, coudn't figure out how to implement it properly. Its throws an error.

```
function* sequenceFizzBuzz(start, step) {
  start = start || 0;
  step = step || 1;


  if ((start + step) % 3 === 0) {

  if ((start + step) % 5 === 0) {
    yield "FizzBuzz"
 }
    yield 'Buzz'
 } else if ((start + step) % 5 === 0) {
   yield 'Fizz'
 } else {
 yield start += step;
}
}


test('Should to get FizzBuzz or just Fizz or Buzz', () => {
 expect(sequenceFizzBuzz(10, 5)).toBe("FizzBuzz")
});
```

Recieve this error: 
    Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received object.

```
  20 |
  21 | test('Should to get FizzBuzz or just Fizz or Buzz', () => {
> 22 |   expect(sequenceFizzBuzz(10, 5)).toBe("FizzBuzz")
     |                                   ^
  23 | });
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, To get a good answer, You must put your error message and any other necessary details here, so others can help you.

Comment: You are getting an empty object (`{}`) as a result of the function `sequenceFizzBuzz(10, 5)`. You need to fix said function properly.

Comment: You have a working solution using ES6 generators like you are trying to do, in this S.O. answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30195668/305953

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FizzBuzz program (details given) in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620665/fizzbuzz-program-details-given-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sequenceFizzBuzz()` returns a [Generator object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*).  You need to call `next()` and get the value.

Change your test to this:

```
test('Should to get FizzBuzz or just Fizz or Buzz', () => {
  expect(sequenceFizzBuzz(10, 5).next().value).toBe("FizzBuzz")
});
```

...and it should work